# List (Property) Access and Inheritance: iteration and modification

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to modify the children from the `SchoolGroup`, but not from the `School`.
How can I implement the same property on the `SchoolGroup` class, knowing that I need to iterate children from any `Collective`, but to add and remove only from the `SchoolGroup`....

```
Class Collective 
  ' just iteration '
  Public MustOverride Children as ReadonlyList(Of Child)

Class School 
  Inherits Collective
  ' just iteration foreach SchoolGroup'
  Public Overrides Property Children as ReadonlyList(Of Child)

Class SchoolGroup
  Inherits Collective
  ' iteration and modification '
  Public Overrides Property Children as ReadonlyList(Of Child)
  ' CANT USE THE SAME NAME.... '
  Public Property Children as List(Of Child)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shadow the property in SchoolGroup so that you're able to implement it with a different return type.

```
Public Class Collective
    Public Overridable Property Children As ReadonlyList(Of Child)
End Class

Public Class School
    Inherits Collective
    Public Overrides Property Children As ReadonlyList(Of Child)
End Class

Public Class SchoolGroup
    Inherits Collective
    Public Shadows Property Children As List(Of Child)
End Class
```

By the way: You might be able to dump the `ReadonlyList(Of Child)` in favor of `IEnumerable(Of Child)`, which basically is a read-only list for enumeration purposes.

Comment: Changed my answer accordingly. Also, if you want to iterate through the property in `Collective` it must be set to `Overridable` instead of `MustOverride`

Comment: +1. I like the IEnumerable approach, since it is read-only by default. A List(Of Child) would then be kept private and ScoolGroup would have methods like AddChild, RemoveChild.

Comment: @DennisTraub: I need MustOverride, because I don't know the implementation in the base class... (so I have no function body, and must force child-classes to override it...)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: "the IEnumerable approach, since it is read-only by default"... This is not always working... if you return a IEnumerable(Of T) from a List(Of T), you will be alble to convert your IEnemerable back to the list, and then modify it... So this is not very secure code... but for the general purpose could work....

Comment: @serhio: However, this will not modify the original list! Even ReadonlyList allows you to modify the children. The only thing a read-only list can do is to forbid adding, removing, reordering and assigning items through an indexer. However, if the items are of a reference type it cannot hinder you to do changes at the items themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer an Interface in this situation since Collective doesn't hold any actual Children data and neither School nor SchoolGroup gain any real advantage by overriding the property.

For example:

```
Public Interface IChildren
    Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of Child)
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class Collective
    Implements IChildren

    Public MustOverride Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of Child) Implements IChildren.GetEnumerator
End Class

Public Class School
    Inherits Collective

    Public Property Children As New ReadOnlyList(Of Child)

    Public Overrides Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of Child)
        Return Children.GetEnumerator
    End Function
End Class

Public Class SchoolGroup
    Inherits Collective

    Public Property Children As New List(Of Child)

    Public Overrides Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of Child)
        Return Children.GetEnumerator
    End Function
End Class
```

This can then be used as:

```
    Dim oGroup As New SchoolGroup
    oGroup.Children.Add(New Child)
    ProcessChildren(oGroup)
```

where process children accepts an interface implementor

```
Public Sub ProcessChildren(oCollection As IChildren)
    For Each oChild As Child In oCollection
        ' Do something
    Next
End Sub
```